# Can you modify a model field within a for loop?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a method that converts temperature units so I can display si units on demand without modifying the database.

When I load the view, `Currently` converts properly as it's not done within a for loop.

The problem I'm having is with `Hourly`. Modifying `data` within the scope of a for loop doesn't change the actual object, but I'm not sure how to modify `temperature` as I can't access the slices by index or like a regular list as I've seen in other solutions.

**models.py**

```
class DataPoint(models.Model):
    ... # Other fields
    temperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def convert_f_to_c(self, temperature_f):
        if temperature_f is not None:
             return float("{0:.2f}".format((temperature_f - 32) * .5556))
        return temperature_f

    def get_si_units(self):
        self.convert_f_to_c(self.temperature)

    class Meta:
         abstract = True


class DataBlock(models.Model):
    """
    Abstract model that provides base weater information block.
    """
    icon = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    summary = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Currently(DataPoint):
    pass


class Hourly(DataBlock):    
    pass


class HourlyPoint(DataPoint):
    hourly = models.ForeignKey(
        Hourly,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='data'
    )


class Location(model.Model):
    ... # Other fields
    currently = models.ForeignKey(Currently)
    hourly = models.ForeignKey(Hourly)

    def get_si_units(self):
        self.currently.get_si_units()    # modifies the location
        for data in self.hourly.data.all():
            data.get_si_units()    # doesn't modify the location object
```

**views.py**

```
class SomeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        location = Location.objects.get(latitude, longitude)
        location.get_si_units()
        return LocationSerializer(location).data
```

**serializers.py**

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializes Location model data.
    """
    currently = CurrentlySerializer()
    hourly = HourlySerializer()
    daily = DailySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = (
            'id',
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
            'timezone',
            'last_updated',
            'currently',
            'hourly',
            'daily',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Create weather data required by Location.
        currently_data = validated_data.pop('currently')
        currently = Currently.objects.create(**currently_data)
        hourly_pk = self.create_data_block(
            validated_data, 'hourly', Hourly, HourlyPoint, 'hourly_id')
        daily_pk = self.create_data_block(
            validated_data, 'daily', Daily, DailyPoint, 'daily_id')

        # Create Location data and return it.
        location = Location.objects.create(
            currently_id=currently.pk,
            hourly_id=hourly_pk,
            daily_id=daily_pk,
            **validated_data
        )
        return location

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Update all weather data.

        # Update Currently data.
        currently = self.update_data(
            validated_data,
            'currently',
            Currently,
            instance.currently.id,
            CurrentlySerializer)

        # Update Hourly data.
        hourly = self.update_data(
            validated_data,
            'hourly',
            Hourly,
            instance.hourly.id,
            HourlySerializer,
        )

        # Update Daily data.
        daily = self.update_data(
            validated_data,
            'daily',
            Daily,
            instance.daily.id,
            DailySerializer,
        )

        # Update Location instance and return it.
        instance.currently = currently
        instance.hourly = hourly
        instance.daily = daily
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def create_data_block(self, data, block_str, DataBlock, DataPoint, id):
        # Creates data block and data points associated with it
        block_data = data.pop(block_str)
        points_data = block_data.pop('data')
        block = DataBlock.objects.create(**block_data)
        for point_data in points_data:
            DataPoint.objects.create(**{id: block.pk, **point_data})
        return block.pk

    def update_data(self, validated_data, data_str, Model, id, Serializer):
        # Updates data for a given object
        data = validated_data.pop(data_str)
        object = Model.objects.get(id=id)
        serializer = Serializer(object, data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return object
```

Comment: post your location serializer. You don't need to modify anything just using `get_si_units` method in serializer will do

Comment: You have `Hourly` derived (subclassed) from `DataBlock` whereas `Currently` is derived from `DataPoint` which has a `get_si_units` method. Does `DataBlock` have the method?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki It's a bit messy and long, but I posted the serializer. I didn't want to put it in the serializer because I wasn't sure how to convert the units and return the serialized data without updating the database. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Sorry, I was selectively pasting things in and missed DataBlock. It does not have the method, but the HourlyPoint class that holds the weather temperature and other variables is linked to Hourly and does include the get_si_units method.